# decoupling dictionaries with the same memory address

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
results = {'location': [], 'analysis_Elem 1': [], 'analysis_Elem 2': [], 'analysis_Elem 3': []}

def collectResults(step):
    new_results = results
    for key in d: #here, d is another dictionary with a lot of results read from .csv file with the same keys as in the results dictionary
        for line in d[key]:
            if step in line[0]:
                new_results[key].append(float(line[-1].strip())/1000)

    for line in d[key]:
        if step in line[0]:
            new_results['location'].append(float(line[-4].strip()))

    return new_results

res1 = collectResults('Time-step 7')
res2 = collectResults('Time -step 2')
```

In this function I am trying to collect results when the if statement is satisfied in a dictionary which consists of keys with corresponding empty lists. The idea is that every time the function collectResults() is called, I'd like to obtain results assigned to a variable; such as in the above res1, res2. The problem I have encountered is that line new_results = results causes that after calling the function for the second time, the dictionary new_results (and therefore also res2) includes the results from the first call extended with the second call. I am aware of the fact that they have the same memory address and this is the reason for overwriting. In case of lists, it could be easily solved with for example list(). I was not able to find a solution in the case of dictionaries. What needs to be done to obtain decoupled results for each call?

Comment: Just copy your initial dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) and replace `new_results = results` with something like `new_results = copy.deepcopy(results)`.

The docs also have a good explanation of why this behavior is happening.

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
>   mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
>   can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides
>   generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).

Answer (score 0):

why not use the copy() method on the dictionary instead of assignment (which just binds the new name to the current dictionary)?

```
def collectResults(step):
    new_results = results.copy()
```